# Accidental deletion of the Gmail (IMAP) Trash 'System Label' in Evolution

Tags: 11.04, evolution, delete, trash, restore

I am using 11.04 and Evolution 2.32.2

I accidentally deleted the Gmail (IMAP) Trash 'System Label' in Evolution.

Because this is Gmail object and (not a label per say), it is not deletable in Gmail. Under my Gmail account settings, I have made sure that both, 'Show in Label List' and 'Show in IMAP' are checked.

That being said, I cannot seem to restore this IMAP folder in Evolution. I deleted the affected mail account, re-created it, re-started Evolution, and no change.

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: This is just to confirm your findings: I reproduced your defect but was unable to find a way to restore the GMail trash (I tried my best!) for a single account. Maybe it's [bug #673591](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/673591)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this issue.

Deleting a Gmail 'system label' in Evolution mail (spam, trash can) means that you are "unsubscribing" the folder. You can re-subscribe by doing the following:

From Evolution Menu - Folder => Subscriptions. Then in Subscriptions, you'll need to specify which account (server), that you are dealing with. In my case it was my gmail web mail account. A list will be generated, and from here you re-check the folder that was unsubscribed. For me, this was the Gmail system label, 'trash'.

Hope this helps others.